# Returning a list of items from a database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  I want to return a list of  value/item pairs to be used in a dropdown box.  I get the following error.

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 
System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem> to
System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
```

My method causing the error is below.

**Method**

```
    //Get the shift list based on StationId which is foreign key in Shifts table.
    public List<string> GetShiftsByStationId(int stationId)
    {
        //Created DataContext to query DB.
        using (DataManager db = new DataManager())
        {
            //returns all the records from table based on StationId in list format.
            return db.Shifts.Where(query => query.StationId == stationId).Select(q => new SelectListItem { Value = q.ShiftId.ToString(), Text = q.Code }).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: your return type is List<string>. it should be List<SelectListItem>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public List<string> GetShiftsByStationId(int stationId)
```

Should be as shown below (because in your LINQ query you are selecting `new SelectListItem`)

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetShiftsByStationId(int stationId)
```